# Bluetooth problem in Linux Mint (Cinnamon)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, bluetooth

I have just installed Linux Mint with the Cinnamon desktop and my Bluetooth is not finding any device, and I cannot find it either. I have checked the `rfkill` and `dmesg` and here is the result.

```
~$dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.030961] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.054061] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.648050] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[13874.011429] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[13874.011454] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[13874.011458] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[13874.011460] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[13874.011465] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[13874.154378] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[13874.155377] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[13874.171401] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[13874.171405] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[13874.171426] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[13874.171428] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[13874.189859] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[13874.189860] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[13874.189863] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[13876.195696] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[13876.281872] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[13876.281880] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[13876.281886] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[15346.946402] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[15352.426182] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15368.041160] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15384.174164] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15400.042260] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15416.174183] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15432.042204] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15448.171207] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15464.042212] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15480.170233] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15496.043226] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15512.170239] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15528.043245] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15544.171263] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15560.042288] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15576.175270] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15592.043275] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15608.171304] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15624.043300] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15640.171310] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15656.044318] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15664.958315] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15672.168321] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[15672.168344] Bluetooth: hci0: inquiry failed: status 0x12
[15683.716367] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[16015.211513] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[16128.356675] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)

~$ sudo rfkill list 
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
7: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please see this. It might solve this... https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=240291

Answer (score 0):

I just find the answer problem is that the BROADCAM series dont have any open source firmware or something like that know I dont know how to find my device VID
https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working/632348#632348